# Get Enum size and name passed as generic parameter

Tags: delphi, generics, orm, enums

Take a look the following code :

```
uses
  TypInfo, Dialogs, Classes, Generics.Collections, ADODB, DB, SysUtils;

type
  TTable_1 = (ID, FName, LName, FatherName);

type
  TBaseTable<TableType> = class(TADOQuery)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); Override;
    procedure Select(DS: TDataSource);
  end;

implementation

{ TBaseTable<TableType> }

constructor TBaseTable<TableType>.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Self.Connection := DataModule3.ADOConnection1;
  Self.Connection.Connected := True;
end;

procedure TBaseTable<TableType>.Select(DS: TDataSource);
var
  Query: string;
  EnumIndex: Byte;
begin
  EnumIndex := 0;
  Query := 'SELECT ';
  while (GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TableType), EnumIndex) <> UnitName) do
  begin
    Query := Query + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TableType), EnumIndex) + ',';
    Inc(EnumIndex);
  end;
  Query := Copy(Query, 0, Length(Query) - 1);
  Query := Query + ' FROM Table_1';
  Close;
  SQL.Text := Query;
  Open;
  DS.DataSet := Self;
end;
```

I use it like :

```
var
  Test: TBaseTable<TTable_1>;
begin
  Test := TBaseTable<TTable_1>.Create(Self);
  Test.Select(DataSource1);
end;
```

As you can see, I write the name of the table in the query as static string ( 'Table_1' ), I want to get the enum name and pass it to select statement as table name to make code more usable.

Another question is how to get the passed enum size to get the field names, as you can see currently I compare the current enum name with Unit name, it's bad idea, anyone can help me?

At least I want to develop a class, write an Enum for each table in my database and pass it to my class and my class's methods use it to Select, Insert, Edit and etc.

I want to write a micro ORM for my personal use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the new System.RTTI unit:

```
function TBaseTable<TableType>.Select: string;
var
  EnumIndex: Byte;
  Context: TRttiContext;
  TableTypeRtti: TRttiEnumerationType;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    TableTypeRtti := Context.GetType(TypeInfo(TableType)) as TRttiEnumerationType;
    Result := 'SELECT ';
    for EnumIndex := TableTypeRtti.MinValue to TableTypeRtti.MaxValue do begin
      Result := Result + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TableType), EnumIndex) + ',';
    end;
    Result := Copy(Result, 0, Length(Result) - 1);
    Result := Result + ' FROM ' + TableTypeRtti.Name;
  finally
    Context.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1. But it is a shame that `TRttiEnumerationType.GetName<T>` has not yet been made public (: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90339